# Can I select United States if my country is not listed?

Tags: ios, ipad, apple-id, user-account

apparently my country is not listed so I'm unable to finish my registration
for the apple ID thing. I'm thinking of selecting United States in there but it keeps asking me for a billing address/phone which I don't have since I don't live in there. So my question is what might happen if I put my friend's US address and phone there? Will it work? or will i face backlash from apple and they're going to disable my device permanently? Thanks

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different :) Can you please specify what country you are from?

Comment: is it necessary?

Comment: It’s just to help you @andrew, would be better

Comment: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/349751/my-country-i-e-bangladesh-is-not-listed-on-the-billing-information might be helpful while the several side questiions get split off or edited out

Comment: god only knows why this question was disabled too. discrimination everywhere i guess

Answer (score 1):

You can put United States as the country for your Apple ID and, if necessary, use your friend’s US address (or any US address at all) as yours. Apple does not try to verify that you are actually from the US or, by any means, you or someone else is associated with that address. However, Apple will ask for a US-based credit or debit card or a US-based PayPal account whenever you want to buy anything from Apple such as music, videos, an app or a service like iCloud.

Or you might keep buying US iTunes gift cards off of the internet (or you may buy them yourself if you are visiting the US frequently or your friend may buy them for you and send them to you once in a while) but the first option is a bit costly and slightly risky and it is up to you to decide about the sustainability of the latter two.

In addition, if you would like or need to [change your Apple ID country](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201389) in the future, you might eventually lose some of the stuff you have bought from Apple until then under that Apple ID.

You can find [here](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202631) at Apple’s support site payment options accepted by Apple.

P.S. You shouldn't need a phone number to [create an Apple ID](https://appleid.apple.com/account#!&page=create). But if you put your friend's phone number in and confirm it for another purpose later on, then, unlike the address, s/he would not be able to use that number for another Apple ID.

Comment: but it's asking for a phone number too! can I like not just put it there and click next?

Comment: You only need a valid email address to create an Apple ID as you can see in the form at [the link](https://appleid.apple.com/account#!&page=create) I also put above. Where are you trying to create an Apple ID? Off of an iPhone, iPad, iMac or a MacBook and through a web browser such as Safari or another app?

Comment: hi thanks a lot for helping me

I am trying to create it from my iPad air that i purchased yesterday

i wish i could send the screenshot

Comment: Congratulations on your purchase and no problem. Is that iPad Air Wi-Fi + Cellular?

Comment: it's i pad air 2019 only wifi. No cellular

Comment: I am not exactly sure how you are getting to some form asking for a phone number as well while trying to create an Apple ID but can you open the Apple ID creation form at [this link](https://appleid.apple.com/account#!&page=create)? I assume if you can create an Apple ID through this form (without a phone number), you can use it on your iPad.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/104601/discussion-between-alper-and-andrewmason).